# laravel 5.5 error syntax when run on wamp virtual host

Tags: laravel, wamp, wampserver

I use wamp virtual host to create url for my Laravel,It work fine for 5.4 below but when i use it with laravel framework 5.5 i have got error:

http://localhost/Laravel%20Project/WordpressAPI/public/

[image]

but I run `php artisan serve` is work fine.

what is something wrong? How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're using an old version of PHP. You have to install PHP 7.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation) for Laravel 5.5:

> You will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:
>   PHP >= 7.0.0